# Delete nodes with certain value from XML using TSQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, contains

I'm trying to parse a piece of XML and remove nodes that contain certain values. I know how to remove them if the value is exact, but I want to use something like a "contains".

This works to delete exactly:

```
update @XML set data.modify('delete //Message[text() = "customer has deleted their account"]')
```

But I want to delete where the "Message" node just contains the text, something like:

```
update @XML set data.modify('delete //Message[contains(text(), "customer")]')
```

However this returns the error:

```
XQuery [@XML.data.modify()]: 'contains()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try

```
update @XML set data.modify('delete //Message[text()][contains(.,"customer")]')
```

to delete the `<message/>` element and its contents

```
update @XML set data.modify('delete //Message//text()[contains(.,"customer")]')
```

to delete the `<message/>` element's contents.

Example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178026.aspx

Comment: Prefect. I'd got to something very similar, but it was a 2 step. Delete the contents of the node, and then delete empty nodes. This is much more elegant.

Answer (score 6):

```
    declare @XML xml = '
    <Root>
      <Sub>
        <Record>
          <Guid>aslkjflaksjflkasjfkljsd</Guid>
        </Record>
        <Record>
           <Guid>opqiwuerl;kasdlfkjawop</Guid>
        </Record>
      </Sub>
    </Root>'

declare @Guid varchar(30) = 'aslkjflaksjflkasjfkljsd'

set @XML.modify('delete /Root/Sub/Record[Guid = sql:variable("@Guid")]')
```

Reference
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40039/how-to-return-xml-node-ordinal-or-delete-node-based-on-element-value